# Adding an image into a ContentControl

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol

I am using an external library, `d3` which has a class named `VerticalAxisTitle` which is derived from `ContentControl`.

As such I was hoping to place an image into `VerticalAxisTitle` via:

```
<d3:VerticalAxisTitle x:Name="verticalAxisTitle">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
    </StackPanel>
</d3:VerticalAxisTitle>
```

and the code behind:

```
verticalAxisTitle.Content = new ImageInfo()
{
    Image = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(@"C:\test.bmp", UriKind.Absolute))
};

public class ImageInfo
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
}
```

However, what I get as a display is simply the name of the class `ImageInfo`. How do I make the picture come out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `ContentTemplate` property:

```
<d3:VerticalAxisTitle x:Name="verticalAxisTitle">
    <d3:VerticalAxisTitle.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </d3:VerticalAxisTitle.ContentTemplate>
</d3:VerticalAxisTitle>
```

Comment: Set the Content property to the ImageInfo object like you did before.